# Spring multiple @Configuration component scanning ambiguity

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, configuration, inversion-of-control, autowired

I noticed ambiguity in component scanning and bean creation when working with multiple `@Configuration` files.

Let's say I have configuration for method level security, which needs to scan packages containing classes that needs to be AOP proxied. These classes are dependent of other classes, and are also dependencies for other classes.

Everything works fine until I scan for that same package in different configuration like in root configuration. Then exceptions like *circular dependencies* and *bean in creation* starts to emerge. Seems like root configuration also tries to instantiate same objects, but of course couldn't do so, as at some point the AOP proxy couldn't be applied in this configuration path and dependencies couldn't be satisfied.

Everything works if I'm ultimately accurate where I scan for what, but I'm surprised Spring couldn't orchestrate the bean creation order automatically. Is this really the case or is there something fishy going on?

Answer (score 1):

This is not fishy. The beans are stored in a AppContext. The design of spring is like: you can have two instances of the same class in the same context! If you configure the MyService twice via configuration, what instance should be autowired? 
See this example:

```
@Autowired
private final MyService myService = null;
```

Because of your scanning worked twice, you have two possible *candidates* for the injection and spring can not autowire and gives a exception (In this case spring looks for a `@Primary`-Annotation, but because you scan twice you have the @Primary twice - so it might not help in this case).

What works is to let the client choose the correct service like this:

```
@Autowired
private final MyService[] myServices = null;
```

This works, you have all instances in the array.

Another option is to have two different AppContexts in the same Application.

Comment: Totally missed out this fundamental concept. I'm working on web app, so having multiple context doesn't fit. Choosing from array violates framework transparency. I guess my only choice is more isolating packaging, but it is kinda counter intuitive, as security is a cross cutting concern. There may be multiple ccc's in a single logical package -> individual components in a same package should be instantiated by different configurations. It would make more sense to scan for those components in root config. I'm looking forward for some best practices about managing multiple config hierarchies.

Comment: Security hm? Scaning a package will load 3rd-party-library beans too, scaning gives the concrete control away, the best-practice maybe to not-scan.

Comment: Can i make bean created in configuration file *transactional*? As far as I know, post processor enabled by `@EnableTransactionManagement` will proxy `@Services` which are annotated with `@Transactional`. Is it enough to define `@Bean` as `@Transactional`?

Comment: Please join the Springframework (Java) chat. I will be there.